# Selectpicker is not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-select

I am using silviomoreto selectpicker. The problem is, it doesn't show the items when I click on the select.

**Html Code :**

```
 <select id="tick1" multiple data-live-search="true" class="form-control selectpicker show-tick" name="tick1">
                <option Value="" hidden selected="selected"></option>
                <option Value="1">One</option>
                <option Value="2">Two</option>
                <option Value="3">Three</option>
            </select>
```

**JQuery Code :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".selectpicker").selectpicker();
});
</script>
```

The thing is, when I click on the selectpicker and press **ctrl + d**, the picker fires and I can use it but it won't close when I click anywhere else.

Thank you

Comment: It should close when you click outside of the dropdown

Comment: It is not closing or opening when I click. I am not able to make out where I went wrong

Comment: just to be nitpicking, please check if you have all dependencies loaded using browsers dev tool. What u see on console?

Comment: Everything works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/sktmet77/)

Comment: Yes. But it is not working when I run the project.. Are there any things outside of css, javascript that i need to check in this case?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem many times.
Adding the attribute data-container to select element should fix that behavior.

```js
$("#tick1").selectpicker();
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">


<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.10.0/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<select id="tick1" multiple data-live-search="true" data-container="body" class="form-control selectpicker show-tick" name="tick1">
  <option Value="" hidden selected="selected"></option>
  <option Value="1">One</option>
  <option Value="2">Two</option>
  <option Value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```